# Question about laserscan and hector_slam mapping

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, 2d-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am using hector slam to build the map with original balgfile odometry data.

The picture is the result with delayed laserscan data overlayed on map. I have set `laser_z_min_value=-200`, `laser_z_max_value=200`, `laser_min_dist = 0` ,`laser_max_dist=200` in the launch file, by which I think all the scan data has been included to build the map.

My question is: what does the color of laserscan particles in Rviz mean? As for area of ① ⑤, the red particles form a boundary, while ② ③ ④ have no red particle(maybe some orange particles), and there is no boundary formed at all. If the color represents the particles of the same height, then why area ④ with high density of light green particles forms no boundary?

[image]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323896/question-about-laserscan-and-hector_slam-mapping/) by [xj yang](https://answers.ros.org/users/32409/xj-yang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2019-05-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2019-05-23**:
what picture are you refering to?

**Comment by [xj yang](https://answers.ros.org/users/32409/xj-yang/) on 2019-05-24**:
The picture I uploaded...

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2019-05-24**:
hmm, no picture for me.

**Comment by [xj yang](https://answers.ros.org/users/32409/xj-yang/) on 2019-05-24**:
That's weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In RViz->Displays->Laser Scan->Color Transformer, you can set the laser scan colours to reflect the intensity of the laser scan. The colour depends on the intensity of the laser scan message received; first, the intensity at each point is normalised, and then a colour is computed based on that intensity. You can read more on the [rviz wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/LaserScan).

---

Originally posted by [curi_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/37504/curi_ros/) with karma: 166 on 2019-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xj yang](https://answers.ros.org/users/32409/xj-yang/) on 2019-05-24**:
Thank you!